# What happen if i use the scripts obtain from tailwind css in the production

Tags: tailwind-css

I am using tailwind css by the  play CDN now the time come for deployment i am thinking that lets deploy it with the scripts I obtain by going on the CDN link what kind of  issue i might face in this my product is simple html to be precise I have DJANGO project since I don't want to include package.json

Comment: If you have a simple HTML product and you're not using much Tailwind then setting it up the right way your overall CSS file would probably be around 10kb. The Tailwind CDN JS file is 490kb and makes sure that your CSS is dependent on that JS loading first. It might cause your app to be slow to load but if you don't mind that extra 1-2 seconds for high-speed network users and 5-10 seconds for low speed network users then go for it.

Comment: i am not using cdn i copy the code which was in the cdn and make a js file will it work fine now 1 or 2 sec slow okey

Comment: Whether you're using CDN or not it will block the render of the page since your CSS requires JS to populate. Depending on how many classes you use it can slow down quite a bit. And you will certainly get a flash of unstyled content. Using the CDN would be an extra .5ms to fetch the content from CDN as well. But if it's a really small amount of Tailwind classes used then you should be okay, but would be far better off with a proper Tailwind build process (autoprefix/nano/purge).

Comment: ok thanks answer this question so that i mark it answer

Comment: one more thing how to collect the static files css once the development complete so store in our static files

Comment: Are you referring to how to do this in a proper Tailwind build process? If so you just need to follow the documentation, Tailwind produces an output.css file in the static file folder of your choosing. If you mean how to save the CSS while using the play CDN Javascript... I don't think that's possible.